# Matrix summation and adding imaginary parts in Fortran easy

Tags: matrix, numbers, fortran

I have an easy question for you. I want to build a subroutine that calculates F matrix in Fortran. Can you help me?

F=(-(w^2)*(M+A))+(imaginary(i)*w*B)+C

w, M, A, B, C are all known.
w is real number. M, A, B, C are matrices sized m*m.. I want to convert all B matrix elements to imaginary number. For instance, its element 453 will change to 453i (complex number). M, A, C do not have anything special. So I hope you can help me to find this F matrix.

Kind regards.
SalimTamer

```
! w is frequency
! M is mass matrix, size(m,n)
! a is added-mass matrix, size(m,n)
! b is damping matrix, size(m,n)
! c is restoring matrix, size(m,n)
! X is excitation force divided by wave length, size(m,1)
! m=n =) (or not invertible)

implicit none
integer :: m,n,i,j
real :: w
real(8) :: M(m,n), a(m,n), , c(m,n), X(m),
complex(8) ::b(m,n)
do i=1,m
   do j=1,n
    C(i,j)=-(w^2)*(M(i,j)+a(i,j))(imaginariy*b(i,j)*w)+c(i,j)+c(i,j)
   enddo
enddo
```

Comment: The code is a long way from compilable, but is `b` actually real?

Answer (score 1):

Fortran has no specific imaginary type, but *i* can be represented as `(0._kind, 1._kind)`.

Your code has `b` as complex, but I assume real is meant.  Two possibilities are

```
C(i,j)=-(w**22)*(M(i,j)+a(i,j)) + CMPLX(0._8, b(i,j))*w +c(i,j)+c(i,j)
!                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
C(i,j)=-(w**22)*(M(i,j)+a(i,j)) + (0._8, 1._8)*b(i,j))*w +c(i,j)+c(i,j)
!                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've used `8` as the kind, following your code, but generally you'd want to go for something portable.  Equally, if my real assumption is correct you know the real and imaginary components of F so you can tidy up.

You don't however, seem to be calculating `F`, and `C` itself is being updated, but hopefully you've the idea.